# Show transparent image on mobile screen at certain time from my application

Tags: java, android, service, operating-system

I have 2 questions:

1. User will set the time ex: 15 min from my application and when the time is up, an image with 2 buttons will appear covering the whole screen for 5 seconds. and then user can select ok or ignore button from here. No matter what the user is currently running, this screen will appear and will be shown on top.
2. Can i disable the power button through code when above mentioned screen shows up ?

regards

Comment: what you want to do is not really a friendly user experience.

Comment: yeah, i know that. But is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question: yes, that's possible. You need the `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission for that. Basically, what you need to do is get an instance of the WindowManager and add a view to it:

```
windowManager = null;
try {
    windowManager = (WindowManager) Class
            .forName("android.view.WindowManagerImpl")
            .getMethod("getDefault", new Class[0])
            .invoke(null, new Object[0]);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("bla", "Error getting WindowManager", ex);
}

windowManager.addView(yourView, layoutParams);
```

For more information, take a look at the source [here](https://github.com/TomTasche/ScreenFilter/blob/29958a186681c1bb9a6199d6584315357ef8c99c/src/at/tomtasche/bestscreenfilterever/FilterService.java).

Disabling the power button entirely isn't possible. You can request a full WakeLock so the device won't fall asleep though.